# displaying post response message of vue-axios

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

I have a function in `APIService.js`

```
createPatient(data){

    const url = 'http://192.168.1.3/api/clinic/patient/add/';
    return axios.post(url, data).then(resp => {return resp});
}
```

And in my vue component script tag:

```
result = apiService.createPatient(data);
console.log(result);
```

but after submitting data received from `apiService.createPatient` is initially pending. 
How can I wait and display the message of resolved Promise ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a data property and then update it asynchronously:

```
data () {
  result: null
},
created () {
  apiService.createPatient(data).then(res => {
    this.result = res.data
  })
}
```

And then conditionally render your component based on whether `result` is populated: `<some-component v-if="result">{{ result }}</some-component>`

Comment: why in `created()` I have made  a function `saveRecord` under the `methods`  attribute that contains the code you put inside created ?

Comment: You don't have to use `created`. I use `created` because it's generally where you initialize your data and for demo purpose only. But if you want to load your data some time later (when an event is fired for instance), that's fine too.

Comment: i think you should only set `return axios.post(url, data);` inside that method